# MAMP - php exec() not working with argument to applescript

Tags: php, applescript, mamp

I'm running MAMP on OS X. In php I'm trying to execute an applescript and pass an argument like so;

```
exec('osascript processMail.scpt test');
```

In the apache_error log I get the following message;

```
processMail.scpt: execution error: Can’t get item 1 of {}. (-1728)
```

If I run the command from the terminal it executes without any problems.

Here is the code in applescript that is receiving the argument;

```
on run argv
set trimmedQuery to first item of argv
```

Note: If I execute without the argument;

```
exec('osascript processMail.scpt');
```

and remove the code that receives the argument in applescript, it executes properly. Something funky is going on with the argument and I can't figure out what is happening.

Comment: There may be restrictions in your php.ini. exec is one of the disabled commands in many webservers, to limit hacking possibilities... What is your position about php.ini ? Are you the one who installed PHP, or are you on a hosted server ?

Comment: @Random There's a php.ini option that allows `exec()` but limits the number of arguments to the command?

Comment: I don't think so, indeed, missed the part you could run it without arguments...

Comment: That's why I'm confused. It seems as though it isn't passing the argument to applescript.

Comment: @user1819087 - Any update on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969743/regex-to-extract-array-of-strings-in-javascript-using-match)?