# RegEx to extract array of strings in javascript using match()

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use `string.match()` to extract column names from an SQL query.

Here is a sample string:

```
CREATE TABLE "listings" (
        "listing_id"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
        "state" TEXT,
        "title" TEXT,
        "description"   TEXT,
        "price" TEXT,
        "currency_code" TEXT,
        "url"   TEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY("listing_id")
```

Expected results:

```
['listing_id', 'state', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'currency_code', 'url']
```

what I've tried:
`/(?<!\()(\").+?(\")(?!\ \()/g`

Is there a way to get column names without double quotes?

Comment: can you provide the expected results.

Comment: What language? What regex engine?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte could you please open the question. I have clarified it, and I am still in need of help.

Comment: @f3lix3rown - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match `"` when its it not followed or preceded by `)` or `(`

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/afzAay/1)

```
(?<![\)\(])"(?![\)\(])
```

then you can substitute it with nothing' so they will be removed

Comment: your regex doesn't match what op requires.

Comment: @VishalSingh he'd totally changed the question; check his edit history

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Use the regex, `/(?<!\()(?:\")(.+?)(?:\")(?!\s*\()/gm` for your requirement.

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/bDWa8m/5) for the demo and the explanation of the regex.

**Demo using Java:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test string
        String str="CREATE TABLE \"listings\" (\n" + 
                "        \"listing_id\"    INTEGER UNIQUE,\n" + 
                "        \"state\" TEXT,\n" + 
                "        \"title\" TEXT,\n" + 
                "        \"description\"   TEXT,\n" + 
                "        \"price\" TEXT,\n" + 
                "        \"currency_code\" TEXT,\n" + 
                "        \"url\"   TEXT,\n" + 
                "        PRIMARY KEY(\"listing_id\")";
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\()(?:\\\")(.+?)(?:\\\")(?!\\s*\\()");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
listing_id
state
title
description
price
currency_code
url
```